# Copy from file from assets folder to my package location for both (sdcard, or internal memory)

Tags: android, android-assets

I want to copy a pdf file from assets folder of my project to the folder where my project is installed, whether my project is installed on sdcard or internal memory.

i saw a solutions says to copy it from assets folder by AssetManager to /data/data/packageName

but does

> /data/data/

means on internal and sdcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never hardcode pathes. Instead get your application's data folder like this:

```
activity.getFilesDir().getPath();
```

Comment: this is actually what i was asking, so ill copy the file from assets to activity.getFilesDir().getPath();

Comment: @MBH this means on your application's folder. This can be either on the SD or the internal card.